# Reading top n number of bytes from HTTP response entity in Apache http-client

Tags: java, networking, inputstream, apache-httpclient-4.x

While reading the response content from the HTTP entity, I will break the data reading loop if the limit reached.

My code will be,

```
       HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
       try (InputStream is = entity.getContent()) {
            int size = (int) entity.getContentLength();
            int readBufferLength = size;

            if (readBufferLength <= 0) {
                readBufferLength = 4096;
            }

            readBufferLength = Math.min(readBufferLength, 1000000);

            ByteArrayBuffer buffer = new ByteArrayBuffer(readBufferLength);

            byte[] tmpBuff = new byte[4096];
            int dataLength;

            boolean truncated = false;
            while ((dataLength = is.read(tmpBuff)) != -1) {
                if (maxBytes > 0 && (buffer.length() + dataLength) > 1000000) {
                    truncated = true;
                    dataLength = maxBytes - buffer.length();
                }
                buffer.append(tmpBuff, 0, dataLength);
                if (truncated) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return buffer.toByteArray();
        }
```

Assume if I downloading 10MB file, according to my code I will terminate the data reading if 1 MB limit reached. But while closing the content input stream, by default it will download the remaining 9MB and after that only I can able to consume and release the connection.

Here my question is,
1)Why it is downloading the remaining 9MB content while closing the connection
2)Is there any way to restrict this?

Comment: For 1) Because it has been _written_ to the other end of the socket, it needs to be consumed.  You don't need to load it into memory or anything though, it can just be consumed and thrown away.  Although depending on the `Content-Type` that may or may not leave you with a completely invalid _first_ 1MB.

Comment: Yes fine, But we are facing a few issues while downloading the page content of few URLs. [http://www.campweekly.com] this server sending the data bit by bit to my client (within 30sec), and my socket timeout is 30sec.  It causes to download this type of single URL takes more than 24 hours. Even if I set hard timeout (set max downloading time externally - 2 mins ), after 2 mins, my code will try to close the stream, at the time again the thread got hangs.